# java.lang.NullPointerException: Activity must not be null?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, nullpointerexception

Here is my logcat.

```
07-03 17:17:01.085 24875-24875/com.example.faisal.fuel_share E/Trace: error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

07-03 17:17:01.165 24875-24921/com.example.faisal.fuel_share E/dalvikvm: 

Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method 
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzacw.zzg

07-03 17:17:18.901 24875-24875/com.example.faisal.fuel_share E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

java.lang.NullPointerException: Activity must not be null
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzac.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaav.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaaw.zzs(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzh$zza.zzw(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzh.addOnCompleteListener(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.example.faisal.fuel_share.FYP_DAO.GetHelpDB.singup(GetHelpDB.java:68)
                                                                               at com.example.faisal.fuel_share.FYP_DAO.GetHelpDB.<init>(GetHelpDB.java:35)
                                                                               at com.example.faisal.fuel_share.GetHelp.singUp(GetHelp.java:82)
                                                                               at com.example.faisal.fuel_share.GetHelp.access$000(GetHelp.java:18)
                                                                               at com.example.faisal.fuel_share.GetHelp$1.onClick(GetHelp.java:42)
                                                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4209)
                                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17360)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**This is my code..**

```
public class GetHelp extends Activity {
   private EditText emailid, nameid, passwordid, phonenoid;

   /*protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
   }
  */



    private TextInputLayout inputlayoutname, inputlayoutemail, 
    inputlayoutpassword, inputlayoutphoneno;
     Button submit;
    GetHelpDB ghDb;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_gethelp);
    initComponents();
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            singUp();

        }
    });
}

private void singUp() {
    boolean isValid = true;
    if (nameid.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
        inputlayoutname.setError("Name is Mandatory");
        isValid = false;
    } else {
        inputlayoutname.setErrorEnabled(false);
    }
    if (emailid.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
        inputlayoutemail.setError("Email is Mandatory");
        isValid = false;
    } else {
        inputlayoutemail.setErrorEnabled(false);
    }
    if (passwordid.getText().toString().trim().length() < 8) {
        inputlayoutpassword.setError("Minimum 8 Character Required");
        isValid = false;
    } else {
        inputlayoutpassword.setErrorEnabled(false);
    }

    if (phonenoid.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
        inputlayoutphoneno.setError("Phone Number is Mandatory");
        isValid = false;
    } else {
        inputlayoutphoneno.setErrorEnabled(false);
    }
    if (isValid) {
        Toast.makeText(GetHelp.this, "welcome", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        GetHelpBean gb=new GetHelpBean();
        gb.setNameid(nameid.getText().toString());
        gb.setEmailid(emailid.getText().toString());
        gb.setPasswordid(passwordid.getText().toString());
        gb.setPhonenoid(phonenoid.getText().toString());
        ghDb=new GetHelpDB(gb);
      /* Intent i=new Intent(this, GetHelpProfile.class);
        i.putExtra("GetHelp", gb);
        startActivity(i);  */





    }

}

private void initComponents() {
    nameid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameid);
    emailid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailid);
    passwordid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordid);
    phonenoid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phonenoid);
    inputlayoutname = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.inputlayoutname);
    inputlayoutemail = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.inputlayoutemail);
    inputlayoutpassword = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.inputlayoutpassword);
    inputlayoutphoneno = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.inputlayoutphoneno);
    submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
  }
 }
```

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it. stackoverflow.com/questions/…

Answer (score 1):

You have not declared and initialized context.Declare it as `Context context;` and initialize it as `context=GetHelp.this;` in your `onCreate` method.
This is causing your NPE.